# ShowFooterWhenEmpty on a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, footer

I have a GridView in ASP.Net4.0 and I have the ShowHeaderWhenEmpty property set to true but I'd also like to do the same for the footer but there is no option to do this?

Is there an option that I'm just not seeing?? If not what is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe there is a ShowFooterWhenEmpty property now :) but currently having trouble seeing it work / do anything :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use EmptyDataTemplate like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EntityGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="DocumentId" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="False" SkinID="GridViewSmall" OnRowCommand="EntityGridView_RowCommand"
    OnPageIndexChanged="EntityGridView_PageIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="<% $resources:AppResource,Title %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="<% $resources:AppResource,Author %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="<% $resources:AppResource,FileName %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="<% $resources:AppResource,Created %>" />
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="EmptyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Resources.AppResource.NoContentToDisplay %>' CssClass="NoDataLabel"></asp:Label>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific property to do this in gridview however there is a workaround which involves selecting a blank row on your data access layer via using `UNION` in SQL but I will not recommend it.

> If you are placing some data entry controls on your gridview just
>   place them in your html markup right after the gridview.